# I am getting an access error while deploying the angular app on heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, heroku

I am getting an error access while deploying the angular app on heroku.But when I build it with the same command on my machine it's passing well.
I have already tried to delete package-lock.json and node modules ,then npm isntall.It didn't work.
Does anybody know why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Error:

```
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
       
       chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 592 bytes [initial] [rendered]
       chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 637 bytes [initial] [rendered]
       chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
       chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 49.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
ERROR in EACCES: permission denied, open '/tmp/build_5fc79d16/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js'
       Date: 2023-01-07T00:28:38.382Z - Hash: dcb91659efb59917b4c9 - Time: 5632ms
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! microsoft-login@0.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `ng build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the microsoft-login@0.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.3gKmp/_logs/2023-01-07T00_28_38_419Z-debug.log
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "microsoft-login",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod"
  },
  "engines":{"node":"10.13.0","npm":"6.11.0"},
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.6",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^2.0.0-alpha.6",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.11.2",
    "msal": "^1.4.6",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a dependency for running a server. Maybe you forgot to add it? like express or hapi, it should be in the dependencies part. Also remember to add a Procfile.

Comment: You were right ,I forgot to install express server after deleting node_modules.Sorry ...